# Is there a Mechanize for Visual Basic .NET?

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping, mechanize

I am looking for a library that is similiar to mechanize for perl, ruby.

Basically, I can `.click()` and it will click on form buttons, or navigate to links, etc.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what Mechanize is?

Comment: See these two questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122614/is-there-a-net-equivalent-of-perls-lwp-wwwmechanize and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080957/is-there-a-headless-browser-for-net-for-automated-web-ui-tests, also http://xbrowser.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Most .NET web bots or scrapers are made with HTMLAgilityPack or HTTPWebRequest. Do you need Javascript support?

This post goes a bit more in depth into solutions: [I need a Powerful Web Scraper library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377355/i-need-a-powerful-web-scraper-library)