# There is any simulated browser for .NET?

Tags: .net, tdd, bdd

There is any simulated browser for .NET like Webrat or Capybara?
I don't need to test JavaScript so using Watir or Selenium would be an overkill.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a headless browser for .NET (for automated Web-UI-Tests)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080957/is-there-a-headless-browser-for-net-for-automated-web-ui-tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean a headless browser like the ones mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2080957/is-there-a-headless-browser-for-net-for-automated-web-ui-tests) SO question/answer?