# I need a Powerful Web Scraper library

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, web-scraping

I need a powerful web scraper library  for mining contents from web. That can be paid or free both will be fine for me. Please suggest me a library or better way for mining the data  and store in my preferred database. I have searched but i didn't find any good solution for this. I need a good suggestion from experts. Please help me out.

Comment: Just a word of warning: when scraping content the site being scraped can drastically change their HTML without warning. One day you've got content where you expect it; the next day they've replaced an HTML table with a DIV or something. It's a good idea to have a contingency plan in place, and to be able to rapidly modify how/what you're scraping.

Answer (score 26):

Scraping is easy really, you just have to parse the content you are downloading and get all the associated links.

The most important piece though is the part that processes the HTML.  Because most browsers don't require the cleanest (or standards-compliant) HTML in order to be rendered, you need an HTML parser that is going to be able to make sense of HTML that is not always well-formed.

I recommend you use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net) for this purpose.  It does very well at handling non-well-formed HTML, and provides an easy interface for you to use XPath queries to get nodes in the resulting document.

Beyond that, you just need to pick a data store to hold your processed data (you can use any database technology for that) and a way to download content from the web, which .NET provides two high-level mechanisms for, the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) and [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)/[HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes.

Comment: Please for the love of. Don't suggest the use of WebClient/HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse for someone needing a Powerfull web scraper! He'd be better of just writing some sockets and loading all the data.

Comment: @Barfieldmv: I'm not a fan of WebClient, as it's too high level, using Sockets IMO is below low-level; it forces you to implement a good deal just to make requests/responses, while HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse has most of the functionality one would need to have a somewhat intelligent crawler built in (cookie support, header collections, etc, etc).

Comment: I guess this is an ancient post, but for the sake of posterity, I'll comment - in our application, which I imagine is not atypical anymore, we have to scrape sites that not only require a login session, but use complicated asynchronous JavaScript, that is triggered when the user clicks on something, to load data from their servers, and whenever those requests complete, goes through a process of updating the DOM. Scraping that is anything but easy. We are a reseller, and some of our wholesalers won't provide any other means of getting product availability information. (Incredible, but true.)

Answer (score 6):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SoftCircuits.Parsing
{
    public class HtmlTag
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Name of this tag
        /// </summary>
        public string Name { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Collection of attribute names and values for this tag
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, string> Attributes { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// True if this tag contained a trailing forward slash
        /// </summary>
        public bool TrailingSlash { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Indicates if this tag contains the specified attribute. Note that
        /// true is returned when this tag contains the attribute even when the
        /// attribute has no value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name of attribute to check</param>
        /// <returns>True if tag contains attribute or false otherwise</returns>
        public bool HasAttribute(string name)
        {
            return Attributes.ContainsKey(name);
        }
    };

    public class HtmlParser : TextParser
    {
        public HtmlParser()
        {
        }

        public HtmlParser(string html) : base(html)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the next tag that matches the specified tag name
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">Name of the tags to parse ("*" = parse all tags)</param>
        /// <param name="tag">Returns information on the next occurrence of the specified tag or null if none found</param>
        /// <returns>True if a tag was parsed or false if the end of the document was reached</returns>
        public bool ParseNext(string name, out HtmlTag tag)
        {
            // Must always set out parameter
            tag = null;

            // Nothing to do if no tag specified
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                return false;

            // Loop until match is found or no more tags
            MoveTo('<');
            while (!EndOfText)
            {
                // Skip over opening '<'
                MoveAhead();

                // Examine first tag character
                char c = Peek();
                if (c == '!' && Peek(1) == '-' && Peek(2) == '-')
                {
                    // Skip over comments
                    const string endComment = "-->";
                    MoveTo(endComment);
                    MoveAhead(endComment.Length);
                }
                else if (c == '/')
                {
                    // Skip over closing tags
                    MoveTo('>');
                    MoveAhead();
                }
                else
                {
                    bool result, inScript;

                    // Parse tag
                    result = ParseTag(name, ref tag, out inScript);
                    // Because scripts may contain tag characters, we have special
                    // handling to skip over script contents
                    if (inScript)
                        MovePastScript();
                    // Return true if requested tag was found
                    if (result)
                        return true;
                }
                // Find next tag
                MoveTo('<');
            }
            // No more matching tags found
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses the contents of an HTML tag. The current position should be at the first
        /// character following the tag's opening less-than character.
        /// 
        /// Note: We parse to the end of the tag even if this tag was not requested by the
        /// caller. This ensures subsequent parsing takes place after this tag
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="reqName">Name of the tag the caller is requesting, or "*" if caller
        /// is requesting all tags</param>
        /// <param name="tag">Returns information on this tag if it's one the caller is
        /// requesting</param>
        /// <param name="inScript">Returns true if tag began, and did not end, and script
        /// block</param>
        /// <returns>True if data is being returned for a tag requested by the caller
        /// or false otherwise</returns>
        protected bool ParseTag(string reqName, ref HtmlTag tag, out bool inScript)
        {
            bool doctype, requested;
            doctype = inScript = requested = false;

            // Get name of this tag
            string name = ParseTagName();

            // Special handling
            if (String.Compare(name, "!DOCTYPE", true) == 0)
                doctype = true;
            else if (String.Compare(name, "script", true) == 0)
                inScript = true;

            // Is this a tag requested by caller?
            if (reqName == "*" || String.Compare(name, reqName, true) == 0)
            {
                // Yes
                requested = true;
                // Create new tag object
                tag = new HtmlTag();
                tag.Name = name;
                tag.Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            }

            // Parse attributes
            MovePastWhitespace();
            while (Peek() != '>' && Peek() != NullChar)
            {
                if (Peek() == '/')
                {
                    // Handle trailing forward slash
                    if (requested)
                        tag.TrailingSlash = true;
                    MoveAhead();
                    MovePastWhitespace();
                    // If this is a script tag, it was closed
                    inScript = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Parse attribute name
                    name = (!doctype) ? ParseAttributeName() : ParseAttributeValue();
                    MovePastWhitespace();
                    // Parse attribute value
                    string value = String.Empty;
                    if (Peek() == '=')
                    {
                        MoveAhead();
                        MovePastWhitespace();
                        value = ParseAttributeValue();
                        MovePastWhitespace();
                    }
                    // Add attribute to collection if requested tag
                    if (requested)
                    {
                        // This tag replaces existing tags with same name
                        if (tag.Attributes.ContainsKey(name))
                            tag.Attributes.Remove(name);
                        tag.Attributes.Add(name, value);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Skip over closing '>'
            MoveAhead();

            return requested;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses a tag name. The current position should be the first character of the name
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the parsed name string</returns>
        protected string ParseTagName()
        {
            int start = Position;
            while (!EndOfText && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(Peek()) && Peek() != '>')
                MoveAhead();
            return Substring(start, Position);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses an attribute name. The current position should be the first character
        /// of the name
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the parsed name string</returns>
        protected string ParseAttributeName()
        {
            int start = Position;
            while (!EndOfText && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(Peek()) && Peek() != '>' && Peek() != '=')
                MoveAhead();
            return Substring(start, Position);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Parses an attribute value. The current position should be the first non-whitespace
        /// character following the equal sign.
        /// 
        /// Note: We terminate the name or value if we encounter a new line. This seems to
        /// be the best way of handling errors such as values missing closing quotes, etc.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns the parsed value string</returns>
        protected string ParseAttributeValue()
        {
            int start, end;
            char c = Peek();
            if (c == '"' || c == '\'')
            {
                // Move past opening quote
                MoveAhead();
                // Parse quoted value
                start = Position;
                MoveTo(new char[] { c, '\r', '\n' });
                end = Position;
                // Move past closing quote
                if (Peek() == c)
                    MoveAhead();
            }
            else
            {
                // Parse unquoted value
                start = Position;
                while (!EndOfText && !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && c != '>')
                {
                    MoveAhead();
                    c = Peek();
                }
                end = Position;
            }
            return Substring(start, end);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Locates the end of the current script and moves past the closing tag
        /// </summary>
        protected void MovePastScript()
        {
            const string endScript = "</script";

            while (!EndOfText)
            {
                MoveTo(endScript, true);
                MoveAhead(endScript.Length);
                if (Peek() == '>' || Char.IsWhiteSpace(Peek()))
                {
                    MoveTo('>');
                    MoveAhead();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple websites ( = plain html only), Mechanize works really well and fast. For sites that use Javascript, AJAX or even Flash, you need a real browser solution such as iMacros.

Answer (score 0):

**My Advice:**

You could look around for a HTML Parser and then use it to parse out information from sites. (Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100358/looking-for-c-html-parser)). Then all you would need to do is save that data into your database however you see fit.

I've made my own scraper a few times, it's pretty easy and allow you to customize the data that is saved.

**Data Mining Tools**

If you really just want to get a tool to do this then you should have no problem [finding some](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=data+mining+tools&aq=1sx&aqi=g-s1g-sx3g-o1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=7b9141da4f416ce8).