# How can I get information off of an external web page?

Tags: c#, .net, web

For a personal project I'm working on, I want to get traffic data off of a website. The website in question shows this in a cell on a table. Can I simply have my program connect to the site, open up the page, and then get the contents of that cell as a string? Using mainly C# in the .NET framework.

Comment: Well, that's the question you asked, "Can I...".  I answered that question.  You seem to be interested in knowing if this is possible; it is.  You can now start implementing a solution in full confidence that you won't later find out it's impossible.

Comment: What you want to do is called **screen scraping** or **web scraping**

Comment: The process you're looking for is called web scraping. There is a lot of different ways to do this in a lot of different programming languages. I found this pretty quickly and it might be of some help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377355/i-need-a-powerful-web-scraper-library

Answer (score 2):

This is an operation commonly known as "web scraping". You can do it manually using WebClient:

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient client = new WebClient ()) 
{
    html = client.DownloadString(@"http://somesite.com/somepage.html");        
}
```

Then parse through the string to look for the data you want. This could be easy or very hard, depending on the complexity of the page you're scraping.

A better way is to use a web scraping library like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a simple GET, use System.Net.WebClient to DownloadString(...) and then look for the cell's content using a RegExpr.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WebFetch](http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx).

It is a pretty good tutorial and sample code on fetching HTTP content.