# Extract urls from whole website

Tags: c#

i want to extract all hyperlinks from whole website instead of single webpage. Is there any C# library for this purpose. If no, then how we can do this ???

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Web Scraping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start from [C# scraping](http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html). You can try HTML Agility Pack for this purpose. Also check a related questions like [I need a Powerful Web Scraper library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377355/i-need-a-powerful-web-scraper-library)

Answer (score 1):

You should try HTML Agility Pack ([here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)). And take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063203/parsing-html-with-c-net/6063226#6063226).