# Download contents of webpage with VB

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic 2010 Express and have found a way to read a file:

Dim byter = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes("C:/Documents and Settings/textfile.txt")

Can I do something similar if I want to read the contents of a website?

Comment: What you want to read a content of webpage or file like archive, image and so on? Either way you need to establish connection, set content type, read bytes and so on

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
  Dim uri as New Uri("http://thewebsite")
  Dim request as HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
  request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
  Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
  Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
  Dim webpageContents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
  response.Close()
```

Comment: I got some errors and the compiler suggested some corrections:  Dim uri As New Uri("http://thewebsite")
        Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)   Then it worked, so thanks!
        request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
        Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim webpageContents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        response.Close()

Comment: The compiler suggested changes so I tried:

  Dim uri as New Uri("http://thewebsite")
  Dim request as Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(uri)
  request.Method = Net.WebRequestMethods.Http.Get
  Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
  Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
  Dim webpageContents As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
  response.Close()
Then it worked, so thanks!

Comment: It worked after some small changes, sorry for the bad editing.

Comment: After viewing the downloaded string I found out it was the html code for the page that was downloaded.   What I really need is the content of the page, like I would get if I marked the whole page and copied it and then pasted it into a text editor.

Comment: I found a way to use the content of the downloaded string, please disregard the question in my last comment.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377355/i-need-a-powerful-web-scraper-library